# How do I save screenshots with automated naming?

Tags: c++

This is what I have to screen shots:

```
CImage image;
image.Attach(hBitmap);
image.Save(_T("image1.bmp"));
```

Is it possible to name the screenshots with a variables? Such as sc01.jpg, sc02.jpg and so on?

I am thinking about doing something like
string namefile + int file_number. jpg

but I can't get it to work!

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Check out for `std::ostringstream`.

Answer (score 0):

U can't use a `String` and add a `Int`variable?

Example

```
ostringstream ss;

for (int i=1;i<NumberOfImages;i++)
{ 
ss << i;
string name = "sc"+ ss.str();

image.Attach(hBitmap);

image.Save(_T(name));
}
```